# Well formed URLs in Grails application

Tags: grails

I have an application, that register a user. I get the user through various pages, and everyone takes some data from the user, that info is stored in the session, and only in the last page, the data is stored in the DDBB.

When the first page is fulfilled by the user, he clicks the "next" button:

```
<div class='btn_sig_pag_uno'>
                <!--  <fieldset id="barra">-->
                <g:actionSubmit action="registro2"
                    title="${message(code:'infoPersonal.siguiente') }"
                    name="siguiente" class="siguiente"
                    value="${message(code: 'infoPersonal.siguiente', default: 'Siguiente')}"
                    style="cursor:pointer" />

                <!--  </fieldset>-->
            </div>
```

The in the controller, in the action "registro2" the data introduced by the user is validated, and "registro2.gsp" is presented... but the url presented is the same than in the first page. I would like it to be controller/action...and don't know why the url doesn't change.

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to create an action to display `registro2.gsp` and then do a redirect after having execute `registro2` like this:

```
redirect(action: "showRegistro2")
```

That way the URL will change.

Comment: The action "registro2" does exists. In fact, it is where the data picked from the first view is processed, validated that the username is unique, the email is actually an email, etc. So, if I put a redirect there to registro2, the action registro2 will be executed twice... and I am passing data from the form in the session, if I do that i lost all the data in the session.

Comment: And if I write redirect:(action:"registro3") The action registro3 will be executed, but there, I process data from registro3.gsp... and since that page is never shown that way, everything will be null. And, if I use render instead of redirect, the url never changes. This should be easy, it's not rocket science!

Comment: You just need to create a new action that will render your jsp, then you need to passe your object to the new action using (redirect(action: "newAction", user:userInstance)). I will advise you do generate the scaffolding on a dummy object and look at how flows are managed in Grails.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way forms work, and the way Grails deals with the actionSubmit. Form submits are by default POST. And since POSTs are about sending data (and not going somewhere, e.g. like a GET), the URL stays the same.

You can change your form to have method="GET", but I don't think this will get what you want when using Grails' actionSubmit since it still uses same URL (but with ?_action_actionSubmitActionName=param as URL param).

Usually you would just do a redirect to another action your action that receives the form POST:

```
redirect(action: "registroFinished")
```

And have a registroFinished.gsp for the end result.